# How to parse bold text in wikitext to html?

Tags: javascript, html, regex

I found a [parser](http://goessner.net/download/prj/wiky/wiky.js), which works great but has some issues. I want to parse the bold text of wikitext. How can I do that?
It should parse `''' My name is Nikhil'''`
to `<b> My name is Nikhil </b>`

I have tried [this](http://www.regextester.com/?fam=95403). It is able to find the text but how can I remove the `'''` tags with `<b> </b>`  ?

Comment: ['''][\w\W]*[<\'''] 


This finds the tag. But Im unable to replace it with <b>  tags

Comment: http://www.regextester.com/?fam=95401 See this. I need to remove ''' from the substitute text?

Comment: Welcome to SO, please be a bit more specific when asking question: what have you tried, what do you expect, etc. See [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Is it fine now? @Ms.Nehal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
/'{3}([\s\S]*?)'{3}/g
```

And `tmplt` should be `<b>$1</b>`.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/nO6nX7/2)

**Explanation**:

- `'{3}` - 3 apostrophes (single quotes)
- `([\s\S]*?)` - Group 1 (referred to as `$1` from the replacement pattern later) capturing 0+ any characters as few as possible (due to the lazy quantifier `*?`)
- `'{3}` - 3 trailing apostrophes.

Note that `[\s\S]` is used since in JavaScript regex one can't use a DOTALL modifier, so, you either use `[^]` or `[\s\S]` (or equivalent) constructs.

**IMPORTANT**: If the blocks of texts inside triple apostrophes are huge, you should use an unrolled (much faster) version of the above regex:

```
/'{3}([^']*(?:'(?!'')[^']*)*)'{3}/g
```

See [another demo](https://regex101.com/r/nO6nX7/3)

Comment: So, I'd suggest `{ rex:/'{3}([^']*(?:'(?!'')[^']*)*)'{3}/g, tmplt:"<b>$1</b>" }`

Comment: Hey @Wiktor. Can you help me with parsing the table format too? Wikicode to parse the table is `{| class="wikitable"
|-
! Header 1
! Header 2
! Header 3
|-
| row 1, cell 1
| row 1, cell 2
| row 1, cell 3
|-
| row 2, cell 1
| row 2, cell 2
| row 2, cell 3
|}`

I need to parse it to html format like `<table></table>`